# Magento 2.4.3-p1: Unable to apply critical security patch

Tags: magento2.4.3.p1, security-patch

I'm trying to apply the following 2/17/2022 Critical Security patches for Magento 2.4.3-p1 from [Adobe Security](https://helpx.adobe.com/security/products/magento/apsb22-12.html?mkt_tok=NTg1LUdHRC05NTkAAAGC61sqFYupmPMI7ir1mjPdjmpLLdvpRIYKcLBakgqBBsGlCYYUNYMg_v5huKRsFi2VzACdlx_6v37eCGDO8cV1EJMKq9HCHrdAKMnCkIb4_6uF) Bulletin APSB22-12.

- MDVA-43395
- MDVA-43443

In accordance with [Magento Documentation](https://devdocs.magento.com/quality-patches/usage.html), I have:

- Added the Quality Patch Tool with `composer require magento/quality-patches`
- Tried to install the patches with the tool, but they weren't listed as available in its "patch status interface": `./vendor/bin/magento-patches status`
- Download and extracted the patches to [Magento root]/m2-hotfixes
- Tried to apply the patches from that directory with: `./vendor/bin/ece-patches apply`

This is when I receive an error:

```
Applying patch .../magento/m2-hotfixes/MDVA-43395_EE_2.4.3-p1_v1.patch failed. 
error: app/code/Magento/Email/Model/Template/Filter.php: No such file or directory
```

It appears like the patch (diff) file is trying to locate the magento modules in my local `app/code` rather than in the `vendor/magento` files.

Do I need to create a symlink or hard replace all the file references in the patch?

Any guidance or feedback would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There should be patch files for composer setups available here:

https://support.magento.com/hc/en-us/articles/4426353041293-Security-updates-available-for-Adobe-Commerce-APSB22-12

You can install it like this:

```
patch -p1 < MDVA-43395_EE_2.4.3-p1_COMPOSER_v1.patch
```

See also https://support.magento.com/hc/en-us/articles/360028367731 (stating that you may have to use `patch -p0 < ...` instead)

Comment: I was able to use those *_COMPOSER_ * patch files in the `./vendor/bin/ece-patches apply` approach. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.